# Need help understanding lists in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Worksheet {
    private ArrayList<DataEntry> data;
    private String title;

    public Worksheet(String title) {
        data = new ArrayList<DataEntry>();
        this.title = title;
    }

    public ArrayList<DataEntry> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Double get(int row, int column) {
        for (DataEntry dataEntry : data) {
            if ((dataEntry.getColumn() == column) && (dataEntry.getRow() == row)) {
                return dataEntry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void set(int row, int column, double val) {
        boolean isNew = true;
        for (DataEntry dataEntry : data) {
            if ((dataEntry.getColumn() == column) && (dataEntry.getRow() == row)) {
                dataEntry.setValue(val);
                isNew = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNew) {
            DataEntry newData = new DataEntry(row, column, val);
            data.add(newData);
        }
    }

    public int indexOf(int row, int column) {   
        int result = -1;
        for (DataEntry dataEntry : data) {
            if ((dataEntry.getColumn() == column) && (dataEntry.getRow() == row)) {


            }
        }
        return result; //to be completed
    }
}
```

I was given this code as practice for my up coming exam and I am very bad at learning new concepts in coding. If anybody is able to understand the code and provide a correct answer to the function *indexOf*.

I understand how user created functions work, I just can't think of what to fill inside this body.

The description for *indexOf* says that it should return the index of DataEntry object in list data using the given row and column, else return -1 if no such DataEntry object found.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that SO is some sort of coding school were you ask people to teach you stuff that is explained in many books and tutorials. Sorry, but that is a misconception on your end. We help with clear, specific questions. We are not a replacement for *you* sitting down and doing that learning part. This is **not** a free tutor service.

Comment: @GhostCat: I agree with you. Still I find that there is always something interesting even in the most basic of questions. For me the positive challenge in this type of question is: how can one explain this very basic topic in the most clear, correct, concise and enlightening manner and add thereby value to the community. In this specific case, I think there is a chance to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the `indexOf` method you will need to understand what a list is; it represents a sequence of items in a defined order. So you know which items are in the list and in which order they are.

For example: you have items "a", "b", "c" in a list, then you know that the list has three items and that "a" is the first item, "b" the second, and "c" the third. If you want to know for example the position of "b", you will need to scan or iterate through the list and count at the same time. When you have then found "b" you have to stop counting and return the current count. That is the result of `indexOf`.

Just a side note: when you count you start at 0 - this means that if the first element is a match, that the result of `indexOf` is 0, if the second element matches, the result is 1. If you do not find anything typically you return -1.

One possible implementation of this logic could be in your case:

```
public static int indexOf(int row, int column) {
    int result = -1;
    for (DataEntry dataEntry : data) { // expression used for iteration, or scanning, or pass through the list
        result++; // expression used to increment the counter
        if ((dataEntry.getColumn() == column) && (dataEntry.getRow() == row)) {
            return result; // returns the count if found
        }
    }
    return -1; // returns -1 meaning: the message 'not found'
}
```

Comment: I understand you have to use a counter (e.g. counter++) but i dont know how to pass through the values in the list

Comment: The expression starting with `for (DataEntry dataEntry : data) {` and which is closed with `}` is used to pass through, i.e. iterate or scan through the list.